# Cannot use a custom font in IOS Application

Tags: ios, ios5, fonts, custom-font

I am trying to use Accord Light SF Italic font in my application.
(Here is the link to the font: http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Accord+Light+SF+Italic/)

I have added the font to my resources, updated in the info.plist, done everything but cannot manage the font to show up.

I guess the problem is with the **name** I should pass to the -[UIFont fontWithName] function.
I have tried many variants, like: Accord-Italic, Accord-LightItalic, Accord Light SF Italic, but none of the work.
I know I should use the system name of the font, but I do not know how to find it.

Please advise,
Thanks!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963299/cant-find-custom-font-ios

Comment: You've registered it in your app with "CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL"?

Comment: @Kedar, thanks! Printing all fonts solved my problem. Answer the question so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your font under **Copy bundle resources** under **build phases**.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I am familiar with the procedure of using the custom font. I have done everything. It just does not work and the reason is the incorrect name of the font when using -[UIFont fontWithName:] method.